# How to convert this PHP Object to an array?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, arrays, json

I have an array in Javascript which is passed to a PHP script via Ajax.

In **file.js**:

```
var params = {};
params["apples"] = "five";
params["oranges"] = "six";
params["pears"] = "nine";
var ajaxData = {data : params};
fetchData(ajaxData);

function fetchData(arg) {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    request = $.ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "script.php",
        data: arg,
    });


    request.done(function(response){
            $("#somediv").text(response);
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });
}
```

In **script.php**:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['data']));
    var_dump($data);
?>
```

The result of the var_dump is:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["apples"]=> string(4) "five" ["oranges"]=> string(3) "six" ["pears"]=> string(4) "nine" }
```

But I don't want to use an object, I want to use it the same way I used the data in Javascript (ie: being able to do:

```
$apples = $data["apples"]
```

Is there any way to deal with this data as an array and not an object right from the get-go? If not, how do I "convert" what I have now into the same associative array as I had in Javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: That is not a Javascript array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**PHP's [`json_decode` takes an optional second argument to do this](https://www.php.net/json_decode)**:

> `assoc`
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Problem solved, by reading the documentation!

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['data']), true);
//                                             ^^^^^^
```